# Divide records into groups - quick solution

Tags: postgresql, select, random, grouping, sequence

I need to divide with `UPDATE` command rows (selected from subselect) in PostgreSQL table into groups, these groups will be identified with integer value in one of its columns. These groups should be with the same size. Source table contains billions of records.

For example I need to divide 213 selected rows into groups, every group should contains 50 records. The result will be:

- 1 - 50. row => 1
- 51 - 100. row => 2
- 101 - 150. row => 3
- 151 - 200. row => 4
- 200 - 213. row => 5

There is no problem to do it with some loop (or use PostgreSQL window functions), but I need to do it very efficiently and quickly. I can't use sequence in id because there should be gaps in these ids.

I have an idea to use random integer number generator and set it as default value for a row. But this is not useable when I need to adjust group size.

Comment: You'll need to explain why you've ruled out window functions - row_number() is the obvious starting point.

Comment: Thanks, but how can row_number() function helps me with this issue? I tried *rank() functions but the result is very slow.

Comment: The "billions of rows" in the base table are irrelevant to the problem if we are talking about a few selected rows. A window function is only applied to the selected rows. So @Richard's solution seems just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query below should display 213 rows with a group-number from 0-4. Just add 1 if you want 1-5

```
SELECT i, (row_number() OVER () - 1) / 50 AS grp 
FROM generate_series(1001,1213) i 
ORDER BY i;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create temporary sequence s minvalue 0 start with 0;

select *, nextval('s') / 50 grp
from t;

drop sequence s;
```

I think it has the potential to be faster than the `row_number` version @Richard. But the difference could be not relevant depending on the specifics.